# [Python]Как объединить словари 1 с 1, 2 с 2 итд. которые находятся в списках

Tags: python, списки, словари

Максимум который удалось получить, но работает он неправильно:

```
list1 = [{key1:value1},{key2:value2},{key3:value3}]
list2 = [{key21:value21},{key22:value22},{key23:value23}]

final_list = []
    for every_dict1 in list1: 
        for every_dict2 in list2: 
            final_dicts = every_dict1.copy()
            final_dicts.update(every_dict2)
            final_list.append(final_dicts)
    return final_list
```

ожидаемый результат:

```
final_list = [{key1:value1, key21:value21},
              {key2:value2, key22:value22},
              {key3:value3, key23:value23}]
```

Что получается сейчас:

```
[{key1:value1, key21:value21},
 {key2:value2, key21:value21},
 {key3:value3, key21:value21},
 {key1:value1, key22:value22},
 {key2:value2, key22:value22},
 {key3:value3, key22:value22},
 {key1:value1, key23:value23},
 {key2:value2, key23:value23},
 {key3:value3, key23:value23}]
```

Comment: Вы же в коде объединяете каждый элемент с каждым (два вложенных for-цикла). У нужно просто первый с первым, второй со вторым и т.д.

Comment: точно, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы в своем коде получаете комбинации. А нужно что-то вроде такого:

```
list1 = [{'key1':'value1'},{'key2':'value2'},{'key3':'value3'}]
list2 = [{'key21':'value21'},{'key22':'value22'},{'key23':'value23'}]

for elem in range(len(list1)):
    list1[elem]={**list1[elem], **list2[elem]}

print(list1)
```

Получим:

```
[{'key1': 'value1', 'key21': 'value21'}, {'key2': 'value2', 'key22': 'value22'}, {'key3': 'value3', 'key23': 'value23'}]
```

Либо, через генерацию списков:

```
list1 = [{'key1':'value1'},{'key2':'value2'},{'key3':'value3'}]
list2 = [{'key21':'value21'},{'key22':'value22'},{'key23':'value23'}]

res = [{**x, **y} for x,y in zip(list1, list2)]

print(res)
```

Получим:

```
[{'key1': 'value1', 'key21': 'value21'}, {'key2': 'value2', 'key22': 'value22'}, {'key3': 'value3', 'key23': 'value23'}]
```

То есть, то же самое.